# Идентификация пользователя на нескольких сайтах

Tags: веб-программирование, авторизация

Имеем 25 сайтов на разных хостах и разными доменами. Посетитель заходит на любой из этих сайтов, проходит процедуру авторизации... Посещая любой другой из этих 25 сайтов он уже автоматически идентифицирован как авторизованный посетитель.

Какие есть мыслишки на этот счет?

Понимаю что нужно писать API для всей этой магии, но честно говоря пока мало укладывается в голове как связать всю эту паутину.

В общем нужны разумные советы реализации, писать отдельный сервис или посоветуете другие хитрости.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализовать своего openID провайдера, как это делают vk, google, yandex. И "другие" сайты смогут через них авторизироваться. Если хорошо проработать, то для пользователя будет практически незаметно.

Comment: Так и поступим. Пойду юзать доки.